# Generating typescript models with openapi-generator is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I am having an angular application and a swagger json file. With [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) I want to generate interfaces from the swagger file. That works, the only problem are models with a whitespace in their names. They result is something like this:

```
export interface Start page {
```

which is not valid.

I am using `"@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli": "^2.4.26",`
with following command: `openapi-generator-cli generate -i path/to/swagger.json -g typescript-angular -o ./path/to/output --skip-validate-spec`

Any idea on how to fix this?